# Does DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE count pager pages (i.e. frontpage?page=3)?

Tags: 7, blocks, caching, paging

I guess my whole question is pretty much in the title... I'm wondering if blocks that use  DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE get cached on pager pages (i.e. mysite.com/frontpage?page=3), or if the pager query is disregarded (so the block would only be cached once for frontpage, frontpage?page=2, frontpage?page=3, etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

See `drupal_page_get_cache()` in bootstrap.inc:

```
if (drupal_page_is_cacheable()) {
  $cache = cache_get($base_root . request_uri(), 'cache_page');
  if ($cache !== FALSE) {
    $cache_hit = TRUE;
  }
  return $cache;
}
```

[`request_uri()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7) returns the whole path including any GET arguments.

Comment: Yikes. So if I have frontpage?page=1, frontpage?page=2, frontpage?page=3 ... frontpage?page=100, then the block will be cached 100 separate times in the db?

Comment: Again, still Yes. :)